# bundle install seems to use the Wrong postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rbenv, pg

so here is what it looks like when i try to run bundle install:

```
   Installing pg (0.14.1) with native extensions 
    Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/kory/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_config
    Using config values from /usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_config
    sh: /usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_config: No such file or directory
    sh: /usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_config: No such file or directory
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... yes
checking for PQconnectionUsedPassword()... yes
checking for PQisthreadsafe()... yes
checking for PQprepare()... yes
checking for PQexecParams()... yes
checking for PQescapeString()... yes
checking for PQescapeStringConn()... yes
checking for PQescapeLiteral()... yes
checking for PQescapeIdentifier()... yes
checking for PQgetCancel()... yes
checking for lo_create()... yes
checking for pg_encoding_to_char()... yes
checking for pg_char_to_encoding()... yes
checking for PQsetClientEncoding()... yes
checking for PQlibVersion()... yes
checking for PQping()... yes
checking for rb_encdb_alias()... yes
checking for rb_enc_alias()... yes
checking for PGRES_COPY_BOTH in libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for PGRES_SINGLE_TUPLE in libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for struct pgNotify.extra in libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for ruby/st.h... yes
creating extconf.h
creating Makefile

make
compiling pg.c
compiling pg_connection.c
pg_connection.c: In function ‘pgconn_wait_for_notify’:
pg_connection.c:2064: warning: ‘rb_thread_select’ is deprecated (declared at /Users/kory/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/intern.h:379)
pg_connection.c: In function ‘pgconn_block’:
pg_connection.c:2594: warning: ‘rb_thread_select’ is deprecated (declared at /Users/kory/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/intern.h:379)
compiling pg_result.c
linking shared-object pg_ext.bundle
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L-Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup'
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_rb_define_module", referenced from:
      _Init_pg_ext in pg.o
  "_rb_eStandardError", referenced from:
      _Init_pg_ext in pg.o
  "_rb_define_class_under", referenced from:
      _Init_pg_ext in pg.o
      _init_pg_connection in pg_connection.o
      _init_pg_result in pg_result.o
  "_rb_define_module_under", referenced from:
      _Init_pg_ext in pg.o
  "_rb_define_singleton_method", referenced from:
      _Init_pg_ext in pg.o
      _init_pg_connection in pg_connection.o
  "_rb_singleton_class", referenced from:
      _Init_pg_ext in pg.o
      _init_pg_connection in pg_connection.o
  "_rb_define_alias", referenced from:
      _Init_pg_ext in pg.o
      _init_pg_connection in pg_connection.o
      _init_pg_result in pg_result.o
  "_rb_define_attr", referenced from:
```

i kut it a short to be brief. but from what it looks like it it is trying to use the wrong postgres. i am not sure why, i cant seem to shake this thing.

i brew installed postgres and it is version 9.2.3 which is why i think it is a little weird that the bundler is trying to us the config file from a version that doesnt exist on my machine(9.1), iwas thinking it was the extconf.rb. because it is the one pointing to it. but i cant figure out how to reset this so my gems install correctly.

```
which postgres
/usr/local/bin/postgres
```

Comment: Seems like /usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_config exists. Try installing it with the --with-pg-config= option referring to the correct pgconfig. Also what does 'whereis postgres' return?